# Finding the running median with 2 heaps

Tags: java, algorithm, heap

I am trying to solve running median problem in hackerrank https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-find-the-running-median and below is my code

```
public class Solution {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt();
        MinHeap minHeap = new MinHeap();
        MaxHeap maxHeap = new MaxHeap();
        float median = 0;
        for(int a_i=0; a_i < n; a_i++) {

            // Logic to add the running element
            int element = in.nextInt();
            if (minHeap.size == maxHeap.size) {
                if (element <= median) {
                    maxHeap.addItem(element);
                    median = maxHeap.peek();
                } else {
                    minHeap.addItem(element);
                    median = minHeap.peek();
                }
            } else if (maxHeap.size > minHeap.size) {
                if (element <= median) {
                    minHeap.addItem(maxHeap.poll());
                    maxHeap.addItem(element);
                } else {
                    minHeap.addItem(element);
                }
                median = (float)(maxHeap.peek() + minHeap.peek()) / 2;
            } else {
                if (element <= median) {
                    maxHeap.addItem(element);
                } else {
                    maxHeap.addItem(minHeap.poll());
                    minHeap.addItem(element);
                }
                median = (float)(maxHeap.peek() + minHeap.peek()) / 2;
            }
            System.out.println(median);
        } 
    }

    static abstract class Heap {
        int[] items = new int[10];
        int capacity = 10;
        int size = 0;


        boolean hasLeftChild(int parent) {
            int leftChildIndex = getLeftChildIndex(parent);
            if (leftChildIndex > size - 1) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        boolean hasRightChild(int parent) {
            int rightChildIndex = getRightChildIndex(parent);
            if (rightChildIndex > size - 1) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        boolean hasParent(int index) {
            if (index > 0) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        int getLeftChildIndex(int parent) {
            int leftChildIndex = parent * 2 + 1;
            return leftChildIndex;
        } 

        int getRightChildIndex(int parent) {
            int rightChildIndex = parent * 2 + 2;
            return rightChildIndex;
        }

        int getParentIndex(int index) {
            int parent = (index -1)/2;
            return parent;
        }

        int getLeftChild(int parent) {
            return items[getLeftChildIndex(parent)];    
        }

        int getRightChild(int parent) {
            return items[getRightChildIndex(parent)];    
        }

        int getParent(int index) {
            return items[getParentIndex(index)];
        }

        void ensureCapacity() {
            if (size == capacity) {
                items = Arrays.copyOf(items, capacity * 2);
                capacity = capacity * 2;
            }    
        }

        void addItem(int item) {
            ensureCapacity();
            items[size] = item;
            size = size + 1;
            heapifyUp();
        }

        int poll() {
            int topItem = items[0];
            items[0] = items[size - 1];
            size = size - 1;
            heapifyDown();
            return topItem;
        }

        int peek() {
            return items[0]; 
        }

        abstract void heapifyDown();

        abstract void heapifyUp();

        void swap(int indexA, int indexB) {
            int temp = items[indexA];
            items[indexA] = items[indexB];
            items[indexB] = temp;
        }
    }

    static class MinHeap extends Heap {
        void heapifyUp() {
            int index = size - 1;
            while(hasParent(index)) {
                if (getParent(index) <= items[index]) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    swap(getParentIndex(index), index);
                    index = getParentIndex(index);
                }
            }
        }

        void heapifyDown() {
            int parent = 0;
            while(hasLeftChild(parent) && getLeftChild(parent) <= items[parent]) {
                int smallerIndex = getLeftChildIndex(parent);
                if(hasRightChild(parent) && getRightChild(parent) <= getLeftChild(parent)) {
                    smallerIndex = getRightChildIndex(parent);
                }
                swap(parent, smallerIndex);
                parent = smallerIndex;
            }
        }
    }

    static class MaxHeap extends Heap {
        void heapifyUp() {
            int index = size - 1;
            while(hasParent(index)) {
                if (getParent(index) >= items[index]) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    swap(getParentIndex(index), index);
                    index = getParentIndex(index);
                }
            }
        }

        void heapifyDown() {
            int parent = 0;
            while(hasLeftChild(parent) && getLeftChild(parent) >= items[parent]) {
                int largerIndex = getLeftChildIndex(parent);
                if(hasRightChild(parent) && getRightChild(parent) >= getLeftChild(parent)) {
                    largerIndex = getRightChildIndex(parent);
                }
                swap(parent, largerIndex);
                parent = largerIndex;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It successfully passes for the first basic test case but fails for all other test cases on submitting code.
It seems to be correct when i debugged it with some samples of the test input.
Can someone review my code and help me understand what the issue is with respect to the current implementation ?

Comment: why not consider using Priority Queue (the built-in Java heap implementation)?

Comment: @AngelaPan I haven't thought about other solutions as heap implementation is very simple and straight-forward. I am not sure what the problem is wrt this implementation that the test cases are failing. Can you help me with that ?

Comment: `implementation is very simple and straight-forward` we've been there.

Comment: people who marked this off-topic should really distinguish "broken code" vs "code that the author sees nothing wrong with." When I first read it, for a long time, I didn't see what's wrong either.

Comment: @AngelaPan: Then, there is [`To the best of [the coder's] knowledge, does the code work as intended?`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and `[This code …] fails for all other test cases`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug with respect to the logic in heapifyDown() methods which caused the incorrect median values

So the corrected heapifyDown methods are below

For MinHeap

```
void heapifyDown() {
            int parent = 0;
            while(hasLeftChild(parent)) {
                int smallerIndex = getLeftChildIndex(parent);
                if(hasRightChild(parent) && getRightChild(parent) < getLeftChild(parent)) {
                    smallerIndex = getRightChildIndex(parent);
                }
                if (items[parent] < items[smallerIndex]) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    swap(parent, smallerIndex);
                }
                parent = smallerIndex; 
            }
        }
```

For MaxHeap

```
oid heapifyDown() {
            int parent = 0;
            while(hasLeftChild(parent)) {
                int largerIndex = getLeftChildIndex(parent);
                if(hasRightChild(parent) && getRightChild(parent) > getLeftChild(parent)) {
                    largerIndex = getRightChildIndex(parent);
                }
                if (items[parent] > items[largerIndex]) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    swap(parent, largerIndex);
                }
                parent = largerIndex;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would offer a test case here. It's a shortened version of test case 1.

```
24
94455
20555
20535
53125
73634
148
63772
17738
62995
13401
95912
13449
92211
17073
69230
22016
22120
78563
16571
1817
41510
74518
81638
89659
```

The median of the 24 numbers is 47317.5
But your program produces 52252.5

Hope this test case will help you find out the issue. There is a built-in Java implementation of Heap: PriorityQueue. If you want to try that out to test your logic.